# How to automate the message sending process on ms teams channel using python?

Tags: python-3.x, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to automate the process to send the message on MS Teams using python. I know that webhook is one of the ways but telling user to configure webhook is not the right approach. Hence how can I automate this process?

Comment: Could you please try sending [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) to the user using a Bot. Here is a sample code in [C#](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) and [Node](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages).

Comment: I have already tried this, [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) are only possible once I get the reference for the conversation. Here I want to send notification/message to teams channel without storing the conversation reference.  Can you also tell me what all things I need to store n order to send proactive messages to msteams channel?

Comment: You would need to store the user's unique id (29:XXX id ) and the tenant id in order to send a proactive message. You could fetch that from team roster if you have the team id and use those details to send a proactive message.